# Why is this question closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

[Write a java code to detect the JVM version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/9121/194) was closed in error as part of the [underhanded](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/underhanded) cleanup. It's obvious from the comment thread that it was never really an [underhanded](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/underhanded) question, and that tag was only added because the system required at least two tags.

I removed the tag and voted to reopen. To my surprise, all three reopen reviewers voted to leave closed. I agree that it's not the best question, but I really can't see why it should be closed. What is wrong with the question?

Comment: Note that the question has now been reopened.

Answer (score -1):

## No objective winning criterion/a at first glance

The winning criterion was tucked in along with the rules, and it looked like just another rule. I've edited the post to clarify.

Comment: "*13. The method used for measuring the best solution is max(n/s), where n is the number of different java versions detected without violating any of these rules (at least versions 5, 6 and 7) and s is the number of lexical tokens in the solution.*"

Comment: @PeterTaylor At least I think it's kind of unclear though. I'll edit to separate it from the rules. EDIT: done